# Show error message when too high or too low when multiplying javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function multiply() {
    const num1 = document.getElementById("number_1").value;
    const num2 = document.getElementById("number_2").value;
    
    if (result > 1000) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Nu blev det för högt";
    } else if (result) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
    } else if (result < -0) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Nu blev det för högt";
    }
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="number_1" value="" size="5"/> * 
<input type="text" id="number_2" value="" size="5"/> = <span id="result"></span>

<input onclick="multiply()" value="Ber&auml;kna" type="button"/>
```

If the answer is higher than 1000 or lower than -0 I want a message in the span to say that it's wrong. What in the code is wrong?

Comment: You didn't calculate the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a value to result first, then move the second condition up one level. Have the result the last.

```js
function multiply() {
    const num1 = document.getElementById("number_1").value;
    const num2 = document.getElementById("number_2").value;
    const result = num1 * num2;
    if (result > 1000) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Nu blev det för högt";
    } else if (result < -1) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Nu blev det för högt";
    } else if (result) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number_1" value="" size="5"/> * 
<input type="text" id="number_2" value="" size="5"/> = <span id="result"></span>

<input onclick="multiply()" value="Ber&auml;kna" type="button"/>
```

Comment: `result < -1`? What about `-1` specifically? OP's condition is proper, minus the fact that `0` is neutral and not negative, it's still valid and proper.

Comment: The condition was if higher than 1000 and lower than -1. Not lower than or equal to -1. So -1 would be a success condition in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the line

```
result = num1 * num2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the result variable absence there are some logical flaws in your code. There cannot be -0 ( 0 is neither positive nor negative), also in the second else if block you are just using result without any condition so the control will never reach the last else if block because a positive or negative value is always true in javascript.

Please fix these issues and repost the question if possible

Answer (score 0):

2 issues: the lack of a `result` definition and the bad `if` statement.

The below code is fixed and commented to explain.

```js
function multiply() {
    const num1 = document.getElementById("number_1").value;
    const num2 = document.getElementById("number_2").value;
    const result = num1 * num2; // NEW
    
    if (result > 1000) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Nu blev det för högt";
    } else if (result < -0) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText= "Nu blev det för högt";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2; // MOVED
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number_1" value="" size="5"/> * 
<input type="text" id="number_2" value="" size="5"/> = <span id="result"></span>

<input onclick="multiply()" value="Ber&auml;kna" type="button"/>
```